# modding an LED fan to tri-color

Tags: led, switches, fan

I'm an enthusiast with little knowledge beyond Ohm's law and I need some help.  I'm trying to mod a blue LED fan in my pc to have tri-color LEDs.  I've done some research and I'm fairly certain I will need a four-state switch.  One for off, one for Red, one for Green, one for Blue.  Any suggestions on how I might approach something like this?  I would just buy one, but I cannot find 200mm tri-color LED fans anywhere.

If this option doesn't work, would it be feasible to set up three rotary potentiometers?  One for each color?

Comment: What type of LED fan do you have? It would be helpful to know the size of LEDs it uses and how they are currently wired.

Comment: It also would help to know exactly what you want to do, set an exact color? Sequence them? Mix them? That and how much you want to spend will determine the complexity of your driver. There's some led strip drive boxes with many features you would need only to adapt the output to drive your leds.

Comment: Are you able to remove the blue LEDs (without destroying their housing)?

Comment: it's a 200mm LED fan (CoolerMax i believe?) with 4 LEDs located in the corners of the rectangular housing.  The LEDs are hot glued into place so removing them would not be difficult.  I also have thought of replacing the onboard LEDs with tri-colors and wiring those into the LED controller built into the case.  What im most concerned about is the chip the LEDs are currently plugged into.  If I remove those LEDs, what's going to happen to the chip on the fan?  moreover, how am i going to power my LEDs without using the fan's chip which has 1 anode instead of the necesary 3 anodes?

Answer (score 1):

4 single LEDs are trivial. Even without looking at your specific fan, most are 12v only plugs. The Chip you mentioned is most likely either a voltage regulator, a current regulator, or a resistor network (multiple resistors in a single package). You could cut the leds out and simply ignore the chip.

As for adding in your own selectable leds, you could tap off the 12v power line, and add resistors and a switch to each led, or you would simply add a new connector wire from the leds to your controller. It only needs four lines, as you would tie the Anodes or the Cathodes together, depending on why kind of light controller you are using.